# Not sure how to download a google drive thumbnailLink using the ruby client

Tags: ruby, google-drive-api

I know how to get the metadata for a google document, and I can get the thumbnailLink value, but I have no clue how to actually download that using the ruby client for the google API.  I'm authenticating using an access_token from the user and would like to download the image to represent that document.

I can't find any example or documentation for how to create a credentialed request to do a simple GET of the thumbnailLink URL in ruby.

I have tried adding the `Authorization: Bearer <ACCESS_TOKEN>` header to the request to no avail.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your replying, I could notice that my understanding for your question was not correct. This is due to my poor English skill. I deeply apologize for this. Since I don't want to confuse other users, I have to delete my answer. I deeply apologize for my poor skill. I would like to study more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was the scope.  The start of this was actually the creation of the google document itself and the scope I used for that was `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file` which says "View and manage Google Drive files and folders that you have opened or created with this app", which you would think would give you access to the thumbnailLink for the document you just created with an access_token generated using that scope, but it does not.  Instead you need to widen your scope.  For now I'm going with `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive` which is pretty much wide open permissions, but will try to limit that later.  But once I changed to that scope I'm able to make a simple `GET` request with the `Authorization: Bearer <access_token>` header and it works.